# Cygwin user name without domain

Tags: cygwin, windowsdomainaccount

I am working on a windows machine that is maintained by our IT department. My user account `me` lives in a domain `dom`, which leads to my cygwin user name being `dom+me`. This is inconvenient because my user name is just `me` on all other machines that I want to talk to with `ssh` and so on. Is there a way to remove or hide the `dom+` part from cygwin?

Some additional details: My cygwin home directory is `/home/me`, so that part is fine. Whoami replies `dom+me`, ssh asks for `dom+me`'s password if I do not specify a user name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ssh can be told to override the default user name by adding the following lines to the file `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host *
    User me
```

Afterwards, `ssh` and `scp` use the default user name `me`.

Comment: I tried the same but it did not work.. Is there anything else to be taken care @klimpergeist?

Comment: @BhargavKumarR, I don't think so. You could try running ssh in verbose mode (-v) to get more information on how ssh is trying to connect.